# ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized with Spring HATEOAS

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I try to use the [EntityLinks](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#fundamentals.obtaining-links.entity-links) concept from Spring HATEOAS.

> EntityLinks is available for dependency injection by activating @EnableEntityLinks in your Spring MVC configuration.

I do it just like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableEntityLinks
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "de.sample.test" })
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
       ...
}
```

Now if I start the application I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7869d479: startup date [Thu Jun 29 13:42:58 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy

Without the annotation the application starts but I have no EntityLinks support.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simple forget the data-rest-webmvc dependency. That wasn't mention in the tutorials I followed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```